# When i m import Migrating to the New Places SDK Client in androidX. can not access getPhotoMetadatas() method

Tags: java, android

I am trying Migrating to the New Places SDK Client and import this "implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'" library and also import "  implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0'" after importing both library in app base gradle.

I want to get location photo from google map please any one help me how to get photo from google map ?

Thanks In advance....

i am trying to access Fetch a place photo method use get place.getPhotoMetadatas() for get photo from google map location.

placesClient.fetchPlace(placeRequest).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
    Place place = response.getPlace();

```
// Get the photo metadata.
PhotoMetadata photoMetadata = place.getPhotoMetadatas().get(0);

// Get the attribution text.
String attributions = photoMetadata.getAttributions();

// Create a FetchPhotoRequest.
FetchPhotoRequest photoRequest = FetchPhotoRequest.builder(photoMetadata)
        .setMaxWidth(500) // Optional.
        .setMaxHeight(300) // Optional.
        .build();
placesClient.fetchPhoto(photoRequest).addOnSuccessListener((fetchPhotoResponse) -> {
    Bitmap bitmap = fetchPhotoResponse.getBitmap();
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
        // Handle error with given status code.
        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
});
```

});

can not resolve method place.getPhotoMetadatas()

Comment: Do you have `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
` this dependency in app level gradle file? If yes then remove it and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import this "implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'" library and update your all libraries of app gradle file.and convert or migrate android project into androidX.